# How to play AVPlayer videos one after another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

How to play Videos one after another on a Button Click using AVPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/) to play multiple videos or play list something like,

```
 AVPlayerItem *itemOne = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: url1];
AVPlayerItem *itemTwo = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: url2];

AVQueuePlayer *queuePlayer = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:itemOne, itemTwo, nil]];

[queuePlayer play];
```

You can add item like while playing,

```
 [queuePlayer insertItem:itemThree afterItem:itemOne];
```

You can refer Apple documentation that i have mentioned in link for more methods and details.